# Retrieve list item information using path

Tags: 2010, javascript, query

**Using:** SharePoint 2010, JavaScript, jQuery 1.10.2, SPServices

In SharePoint 2010 I have a custom (JavaScript-based) page where users may type in text and link to items in SharePoint lists.  A recent requirement has made it necessary to also include the Modified date, something I'd like to do automatically, since I can't expect users to think to update this page every time they update the linked document.

As an example, if a user has the text "Information Paper" linked to the item stored at https://mysite.com/sites/123/1234/MyPaper.docx, the script needs to be able to extract the URL from the anchor tag (already working), use the path and file name to locate the exact item, gather the Modified date on the file, and append it to the existing link text.  That way, the user's "Information Paper" becomes "Information Paper (11 April 2014)".

It looks like SPServices' Query operation may be able to handle this, but I don't know how/if I can use a path to return the specific item's information.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would use SPServices GetListItems operation and specify the CAMLQuery option with a CAML query designed to only get the item(s) with your URL.

Example:

```
 $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "YOUR LIST NAME",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Text'>1234/MyPaper.docx</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var modifiedDateTime = $(this).attr("ows_Modified");
      });
    }
  });
```

The FileRef field is stored as "Library/Folder/filename.extention" so make sure you strip off the root URL to the site from the absolute URL you are starting with.

Comment: Thanks, for your response, Jared! This approach sounds good, but the listName variable could be different from link to link.  In my example above, the path would be "/sites/123/" and the list name would be "1234", but the URL could just as easily contain numerous folders or a number of subsite levels.  URLs potentially differ from link to link.  I'll test your approach and see if SPServices is smart enough to determine the list name from a full path.

Comment: Very good. I understand that adds some complexity to the task. Unfortunately I can't offer too much more since all of the jQuery and SPServives approaches rely on the GetListItems web method which is always going to require you to specify the list/library in question. The only thing I can think of would be to recursively call starting with the known top level site, going down each rout in the URL until you find the document in question. Would make the process relly "chatty" but would work in principle.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, and is likely the direction I'll go.  I appreciate you taking the time to offer your insight.

Comment: Good luck! Let us know how you end up solving it.

Comment: Still poking at this.  So far I've been able to separate the path and file name but SPServices chokes for some reason.  I pass in the listName and webURL since files are stored in subsites, but once I get inside completefunc, I'm not getting access to $(this).attr("ows_Modified").  I'll try a question on the SPServices site to make sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks to the help above, I was able to get it working.  The main problem was in the variable I was passing in; it needed to contain "sites/unit/subUnit/library/folder/subFolder/fileName.docx" in order to let the query within GetListItems to work.  See this exchange for actual code samples: https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/543350.  Thank you again, Jared, for pointing me in the right direction.  Your advice broke this open for me.